# Jruby/Vert.x, Setup issue

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, vert.x

I just recently learned about Vert.x and would like to try it out but I am running into some issues.

I can get a server up written in javascript but cannot get the ruby (jruby) version to run.

> May 04, 2012 1:50:57 PM org.vertx.java.core.logging.impl.JULLogDelegate error
>   SEVERE: backtrace is
>   /home/curtis/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.6/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in
>   `require'
>   /home/curtis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/json-1.6.6/lib/json/ext.rb:13:in`
>   Ext'
>   /home/curtis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/json-1.6.6/lib/json/ext.rb:12:in
>   `JSON'
>   /home/curtis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/json-1.6.6/lib/json/ext.rb:9:in`
>   (root)'
>   /home/curtis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/json-1.6.6/lib/json/ext.rb:36:in
>   `require'
>   /home/curtis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/json-1.6.6/lib/json.rb:58:in`
>   JSON'
>   /home/curtis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/json-1.6.6/lib/json.rb:54:in
>   `(root)'
>   /home/curtis/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/json-1.6.6/lib/json.rb:59:in`
>   require'
>   /home/curtis/src-files/vert.x-1.0.beta11/bin/../lib/ruby/core/event_bus.rb:16:in
>   `(root)'
>   /home/curtis/src-files/vert.x-1.0.beta11/bin/../lib/ruby/core/event_bus.rb:26:in`
>   (root)'
>   /home/curtis/src-files/vert.x-1.0.beta11/bin/../lib/ruby/vertx.rb:1:in
>   `(root)'

This is what happens when I try to simply run the webapp example located in the `vert.x-1.0.beta11/examples/ruby/webapp` directory. I do have Jruby installed (through rvm)

> $ jruby-1.6.6 -v jruby 1.6.6 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) (2012-01-30 5673572)
>   (OpenJDK Client VM 1.7.0_147-icedtea) [linux-i386-java]

I also have the reccomended JDK/JRE version installed. With the correct paths

**.bashrc (bottom)**

> PATH=$PATH$HOME/.rvm/bin:$HOME/src-files/vert.x-1.0.beta11/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-i386

I am running into a brick wall sort of, the error messages either don't help much or lead me to believe there is simply a bug in vert.x or jruby.

Advice please?

> JRUBY_HOME=$HOME/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have json gem installed, it's a prerequisite for the running the ruby version as stated on the [vert.x website](http://vertx.io/install.html). Since you're using rvm you can switch to jruby, `rvm use [jruby-version]` if you've not already and try searching for the json gem as shown below.

`gem search json`

What is the result when you issue the command above. If you didn't get any response, you can get it installed in your jruby by using this command,

`jruby -S gem install json`

On the lighter side you should also install yard gem if you want to build the ruby API doc. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is the `PATH` line in your .bashrc just as you wrote here? If so, you need a slash in between `$PATH` and `$HOME`. Also, I think rvm likes to have the rvm sourcing line as the last thing in .bashrc, like the following:

```
# RVM -- don't put anything after this.
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin # Add RVM to PATH for scripting
```